# How to run command conditionally in docker compose

Tags: bash, docker, syntax, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to run command conditionally in docker-compose

because when someone run this application at first time,

They would have to run `migrate` command so that they can run `django` application properly

But If their docker have run `migrate`, there is no need to run `migrate` again

So this is the command to check that their docker have run `migrate`.

```
    if [[ -z $(python3 zeus/manage.py showmigrations | grep '\[ \]')]]; then
        echo 'no need to migrate'
    else
        echo 'need to migate'
    fi
```

This is my docker-compose.

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    command: >
         bash -c "if [[ -z $(python3 zeus/manage.py showmigrations | grep '\[ \]')]]; then
               echo 'no need to migrate'
            else
               echo 'need to migate'
            fi && python3 zeus/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
         "
```

But Error occurs like this

```
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "build" option in service 
"web": "bash -c "if [[ -z $(python3 zeus/manage.py showmigrations | grep '\[ \]')]]; then 
echo 'no need to migrate' else echo 'need to migate' fi 
&& python3 zeus/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000""
```

Any idea?

### Edit

This is fine when I run the script of checking migration in normal bash

I think docker-compose can't parse `$(python3 manage.py .....)` part.

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your bash script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: This is fine when I run that script in bash. However, That error occurs in docker-compose.yml

Comment: first thing you need to add a sapce before the last `]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    command: bash -c "if [[ -z $$(python3 zeus/manage.py showmigrations | grep '\\[ \\]') ]]; then
               echo 'no need to migrate';
            else
               echo 'need to migate';
            fi && python3 zeus/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

three problems were there , you need to escap the escape charachter `\` and add more `$` to escape the replacment in compose and one more space before the last `]]`

Comment: No error occurs like `this Invalid interpolation format for "build" option in service`, but occurs like this `web_1  | bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: But it is no luck for me. I can share my code for compose file. https://github.com/RayKimEX/docker-compose-stackover-flow/blob/master/docker-compose.dev.yml

Comment: Anyway, I appreicate about answer. It helps me. Thank you

Comment: No error occurs but It print messages like `no need to migrate else echo need to migate`. It doesn't seems to work with `if statements` properly

Comment: and onther ";" after `echo 'no need to migrate'` :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid writing complicated scripts in `docker-compose.yml`, especially if they're for normal parts of your application setup.

A typical pattern is to put this sort of setup in an entrypoint script.  That script ends with the shell command `exec "$@"`.  In a Docker context, that tells it to replace itself with the command (from a Dockerfile `CMD` statement or Docker Compose `command:`).  For your example this could look like

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z $(python3 zeus/manage.py showmigrations | grep '\[ \]')]; then
    echo 'no need to migrate'
else
    echo 'need to migate'
fi
exec "$@"
```

Then in your Dockerfile, copy this file in and specify it as the `ENTRYPOINT`; leave your `CMD` that runs your application unmodified.

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /app
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD python3 zeus/manage.py run --host=0.0.0.0:8000
```

The `ENTRYPOINT` statement must be the JSON-array form and must not have an explicit `sh -c` wrapper in it.

If you want to verify that things have gotten set up correctly, you can run

```
docker-compose run web sh
```

and you will get a shell at the point that `exec "$@"` is: after your migrations and other setup have run, but instead of your main server process.

Comment: I tried this script in Dockerfile. However Dockerfile doesn't recognize the name of host `db` which is defined in compose. so i can't run command of `migrate` because. `migrate` command have something to do with the name of host `db`